# How to hide a div when the input is out of focus?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am trying to show the recent searches when an user clicks to the input form to type something. And hide it when the user clicks outside of the input box. I'm using Vue (`v3.2.29`).

I've got the first part(showing the `div` when user clicks the input box) working but cannot solve the second part of the problem.

Apparently there is no straightforward way in JavaScript to tell whether the DOM is in focus or not.

This what my function for this looks like:

```js
const showRecentSearches = () => {
  if (document.getElementById("search-box") === document.activeElement) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};
```

This works fine for showing the `div` when the input is in focus but fails to hide it when it is out of focus.

Edit: [This code from a discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/ndelvalle/v-click-outside/issues/238#issuecomment-713872610) solves the problem with a custom directive for `click-outside` event.

Comment: Rename `search-box` to `searchBox` and then you can rewrite your function `const showRecentSearches = () => document.activeElement === searchBox;`

Comment: @isherwood I'm using the vue directive `v-if` to conditionally render the `div`. So, it's `v-if=showRecentSearches`.

Comment: @JeremyThille That surely works but it has the same problem - it doesn't hide the div when input is out of focus. But it's much cleaner than my function for sure.

Comment: Oh yeah I know, it won't solve your problem, that was a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Your answer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event

Comment: Wait, `v-if`? You are using Vue? That's a crucial information you have not mentioned! I've updated the tags. Why would you use `document.getElementById` in a Vue application? Have a look at this, I believe it will help : https://thewebdev.info/2021/05/17/how-to-detect-clicks-outside-an-element-with-vue-js/

Comment: You need to put the answers to our questions in your post, not down here. Don't make your volunteer helpers scrounge for information.

Comment: @JeremyThille Thanks! The article gives the solution in terms of Vue2 but as I am working with Vue3, some changes needed to be made. Here is the [custom directive code](https://github.com/ndelvalle/v-click-outside/issues/238#issuecomment-713872610) that worked for me.